# Can we give same scrolling to the inner RecylerView as a Parent Recylerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to know , I have two `RecylerView` one is `parent RecylerView` and another is `child RecylerView` in the same orientation (Vertical) , but when I am touching the child RecylerView then I am not able to scroll the `parent RecylerView` but the `child RecylerView` is not scrolling at all.

Comment: A nested scrollview? I think you should reconsider your approach, since it might not end up in an intuitive user experience. What is your goal?

Comment: @Christopher My goal is to scroll the child recylerview inside the parent recylerview . Actually in my app , there is a parent recylerview which contains the child recylerview , what i want to do when scroll the child recylerview then parent recylerview should not scroll

Comment: @Christopher problem is that my child recyleview is not scrolling at all but get the touch intercept to block the parent recylerview